# Smalltalk with support when waiting for a system to restart

Tags: socializing

I've been on the line with support while a system is rebooting. The both of us had to wait for 10 minutes. I was wondering what appropriate smalltalk one could engage in while waiting?

We're both just waiting anyway, so we might as well have a conversation.

Comment: I personally don't think small talk is necessary. You may have been waiting for your system to reboot, but the person on the other end was most certainly using their computer. I'll usually be on my smartphone reading something. Then again, I am an introverted engineer...

Comment: @DavidK - If you're going to be doing phone support, you may want to pretend you're not an "introverted engineer" in front of a customer.

Comment: @JeffO, I am speaking as the customer. If I were the phone support I wouldn't start any small talk, but I would participate if the customer started it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be about small talk, not workplace behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

> Well, how's your day been so far?

How do you start a conversation with someone you don't know, maybe on the other side of the world?  Keep things friendly but non-contentious.  Giving someone a chance to unload can be a good way to get them on your side.

Answer (score 1):

I do. I usually ask them what City they are in.  But you have to consider they may be using that time to do other stuff like check email or StackExchange.  If they don't want to engage then let it go quite.